Google Cloud, deploying artifact registry docker image to Compute Engine fails with "No startup scripts to run." instead of running docker file
As the title says, I'm trying to deploy a Docker Image to a Compute Engine instance.  I've tried via various routes (e.g. creating a suitable e2 instance and choosing the image to be deployed, or going to the image in Artifact Registry and choosing the option to deploy to GCE).  I cannot understand why it isn't running, and docs do not suggest that it should be doing this.  I don't see any suggestions that a startup script would be required to do this.  The docker image works fine when run locally.  Am I missing something stupidly simple?
VM Details:

Location: us-east1-b
Machine type: e2-micro
CPU platform: Intel Broadwell
Architecture: x86/64
Container image: europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/{project}/{dir}/{image-name}:{tag}
Boot Disk image: Google, Container-Optimized OS 117-18613.75.37 LTS


The e2-micro instance has limited resources, so make sure your container’s CPU and memory requirements don’t exceed its capacity. If issues persist, try manually running the container and check the logs for errors:

sudo docker run -d --name my-container europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/{project}/{dir}/{image-name}:{tag}

Also, check Container-Optimized OS logs for Docker issues:

sudo journalctl -u docker

Ensure the VM has the necessary Artifact Registry permissions and that outbound access to the registry is allowed if the VM is behind a firewall.
